# Form Date POSTing as null

Tags: forms, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

Does anyone have experience with trying to POST a date form successfully? I think this is a JS problem and not so much a formatting issue with python, but I could be wrong.

When I submit the form on my frontend, I can see start_date and end_date listed as such:
[image]

**This is the same thing that I see in the network tab also when I post to my API using the DRF API site.**

However, in the failed response tab, both date fields turn out to not have been populated.

```
end_date: ["This field is required."]
start_date: ["This field is required."]
```

**Vue Template**

```
 Start Date
      <input
        type="date"
        id="start"
        name="trip-start"
        min="2021-01-01"
        max="2022-12-31"
        v-model="form.startDate"
      />
      End Date
      <input
        type="date"
        id="start"
        name="trip-start"
        min="2021-01-01"
        max="2022-12-31"
        v-model="form.endDate"
      />
```

```
data() {
    return {
      form: {
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
        user: this.$store.getters.loggedInUser.id
      }
    };
  }
```

**Models.py**

```
class Listings(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT, default="1")
    start_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=False)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ListingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: But in your `data()` method, you specify `form : { startDate: null, ... }`?

Comment: Oh hey, I'm guessing you're not familiar with Vue, basically in my template there's a field called *v-model*. The value I enter in my form gets sent to data() via the v-model. That's why I can see the input on the Headers page of the Network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The issue was that my backend was named 'end_date' while my front end was sending endDate.